# Ruby on rails Bootstrap Modal not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

[My modal does not appear and there is only a black overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt5D4.png)

I am using

```
Rails version             6.0.1
Ruby version              ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin18]
RubyGems version          3.0.6
Rack version              2.0.7
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
```

My code is largely similar to this: https://dzone.com/articles/rails-creating-modals

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Add user', new_item_path,  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'}  %>
<div id="modal-window" class="modal fade hide" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_new.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= simple_form_for @item do |f| %>            
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Todo", required: true, id: "font-colour" %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :category %>
    <%= f.input :expiryDate, label: "Expiry Date", as: :date %>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'submit' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

new.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j (render 'new') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal("show");
```

in the controller:

```
  def new
    @item = Item.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I tried removing hide from the class="modal fade hide" and also changing .modal("show") to .show()

I have looked at other similar posts:

[Bootstrap modal in ruby on rails not working(not show up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491685/bootstrap-modal-in-ruby-on-rails-not-workingnot-show-up)

[Bootstrap modal in ruby on rails not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028730/bootstrap-modal-in-ruby-on-rails-not-working)

[Bootstrap Modal Not Appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230860/bootstrap-modal-not-appearing)

Comment: If you need to use javascript to activate bootstrap modal, do not use data attribute.

Comment: sorry, I am new to ruby on rails. Are you referring to this 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'?

Comment: yes. read [bootstrap 4 modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) documentation also.

Comment: I see from the documentation that data attributes are not required but in this case, how do I solve this problem. Because I tried removing them but now even the overlay does not appear